# common Header and Footer files in web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dreamweaver

I've created a header.html and footer.html file and placed the jquery code (shown below) in the head of my index page. Works like a charm. But when I place this code on other web pages everything works - except my DreamWeaver Spry Menu Bar doesn't function correctly (shown below I changed to "../header.html" and "../footer.html" since other web pages are in folders). Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Services</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("../header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("../footer.html"); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="hero"> </div>
<div id="content">Content for  id "content" Goes Here</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what it supposed to look like DreamWeaver Spry Menu Bar??fiddle please..

Comment: Should this path: `<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` also be `<script src="../SpryAssets/..."></script>`?

Comment: Are you able to see the script getting loaded in netwrk tab of chrome?

Comment: omgosh THANK YOU beercodebeer! That did the trick. I completely overlooked that. oops!